# creating a number pattern with day number

Tags: java, numbers, days

Okay so I need to make a number pattern with day numbers for example: 1 - monday, 2 - tuesday, 3 - wednesday until 7 - sunday. If I put an input "n" I would get the following:

n=4
1 2 3 4

n=7
1 2 3 4 5 6 7

n=12
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5

I've succeeded making this program if n<=14 but if n>14 I get:
n=17
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
when it should be:
n=17
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3

this is my code

```
for (x=1;x<=n;x++){
    System.out.print(x+" ");
    if (x==7){
        for (x=1;x<=(n-7);x++)
        System.out.print(x+" ");
        break;
    }
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is your problem or what exactly you want to achieve? Better looking code?

Comment: the program that i coded goes out of pattern if n>14, so for example n=16, it ends like: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 when it should be: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    System.out.print(i % 7 + 1 + " ");
```

Whenever you want to have that "repeating" behavior, where a sequence of numbers goes up to a certain value and then restarts, use the `%` operator and a bit of modular arithmetic to achieve the desired effect. For `n = 17` the above will print:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3
```

Comment: @user2868984 The `%` operator takes the remainder of the division between `i` and `7`, and we add `1` to get the numbers in the range `1..7` instead of `0..6`. It's an arithmetic trick, it has nothing to do with string formatting

Comment: btw, is this the only way? I mean, is there a way by using if like what I have tried?

Comment: @user2868984 no, of course it could have been done with your approach, but as you can see, getting the indexes and the conditions right requires some fiddling. Try to do it your way, just for practice ;)

Comment: any hints for what I'm doing wrong, or what I have to add? haha ;)

Comment: Wow I did it using conditional statements!! I change the if condition to `if(x==7&&(n-7)<=7)` and added an `else if (x==7&&(n-7)>7)` with `x=0; n-=7; continue;` as statements. Thanks a ton for the ideas!!!

Comment: @user2868984 here's one way: `for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= n; i++) { System.out.print(j + " "); if (j == 7) j = 1; else j++; }`